# javascript delay popup

Tags: javascript, popup

im having a prob with javascript which has been bugging me for hours now. I need to delay a css popup so that if you just scroll mouse around page you wont get loads of popups.

Whatever i try it either makes the popup act goofy, poping up after x seconds with a swipe of any link, auto closing etc etc. if i add a timer to the mouseover it starts acting weird, if i then delete the timer for mouseout it works fine but you can no longer mouseover menu before it closes, also tried adding negative margin and it autocloses

cheers all

javscript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var span = document.querySelectorAll('.pop');
for (var i = span.length; i--;) {
(function () {
    var t;
    span[i].onmouseover = function () {
        hideAll();
        clearTimeout(t);
        this.className = 'popHover';
    };
    span[i].onmouseout = function () {
        var self = this;
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            self.className = 'pop';
        }, 300);
    };
})();
}

function hideAll() {
 for (var i = span.length; i--;) {
    span[i].className = 'pop'; 
    }
};
</script>
```

css

```
.pop {
position:relative;
   }
    .pop div {
    display: none;
    }

.popHover {
position:absolute;
}

.popHover div {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-color:#AAAAAA;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px 2px 2px 1px;
color:#333333;
padding:5px;
position:absolute;
z-Index:9999;
width:150px;
display: inline-block;
 margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery might be a little more helpful for what you are trying to do. Try something like this:

```
// Use a CDN to take advantage of caching
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t;
$('.pop').on('mouseover', $.proxy(function () {
    hideAll();
    clearTimeout(t);
    this.addClass('popHover');
    this.removeClass('pop');
}, this));

$('.pop').on('mouseout', $.proxy(function () {
    var self = this;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        self.addClass('pop');
        self.removeClass('popHover');
    }, 300);
},this));


function hideAll() {
    // Since you are calling this from the mouseover function of all the
    // elements with the 'pop' class, I dont understand what the purpose of this class
    // is so it might not be entirely correct.
    $('.pop').addClass('pop');
}
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps. If you still need it. It would be helpful to have a fiddle to maybe tweak to give you a more accurate response.